# how to display the json values using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

Below is my code that shows movie data from the JSON variable, and displays it on the drop down list based on the selected city. I need to show the show timings along with other details from the JSON content.

The following is my code :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var cityData = [
        {
            cityName: 'Bengaluru',
            value: 'Bengaluru',
            data: [
                {
                    movieName: 'ABC',
                    theaterName: 'Tulsi Theatre',
                    showTImings:['8:00AM','12:00PM','4:00PM','9:00PM']
                },
                {
                    movieName: 'DEF',
                    theaterName: 'PVR',
                    showTImings:['8:00AM','12:00PM','4:00PM','9:00PM']
                },
                {
                    movieName: 'GHI',
                    theaterName: 'Srinivasa Theatre',
                    showTImings:['8:00AM','12:00PM','4:00PM','9:00PM']
                },
            ],
        },
        {
            cityName: 'Hyderabad',
            value: 'Hyderabad',
            data: [
                {
                    movieName: '123',
                    theaterName: 'Theatre1',
                    showTImings:['8:00AM','12:00PM','4:00PM','9:00PM']
                },
                {
                    movieName: '456',
                    theaterName: 'PVR2',
                    showTImings:['8:00AM','12:00PM','4:00PM','9:00PM']
                },
                {
                    movieName: '789',
                    theaterName: 'Theatre3',
                    showTImings:['8:00AM','12:00PM','4:00PM','9:00PM']
                },
            ],
        },

        {
            cityName: 'Guntur',
            value: 'Guntur',
            data: [
                {
                    movieName: 'ABC1',
                    theaterName: 'Theatre4',
                    showTImings:['8:00AM','12:00PM','4:00PM','9:00PM']
                },
                {
                    movieName: 'DEF2',
                    theaterName: 'PVR3',
                    showTImings:['8:00AM','12:00PM','4:00PM','9:00PM']
                },
                {
                    movieName: 'GHI3',
                    theaterName: 'Theatre5',
                    showTImings:['8:00AM','12:00PM','4:00PM','9:00PM']
                },
            ],
        },

        {
            cityName: 'Ongole',
            value: 'Ongole',
            data: [],
        },
    ];
    
    var locations = [] ;
    $('#selectCity').on('change', function() {
        if ($(this).val().indexOf('City') === -1) {locations = cityData.filter( c => c.cityName === $(this).val(),)[0].data;
            var locationString = '';
            var locationString2 = '';
            $.each(locations, function(i, item) {
                locationString +='<option value="' +item.theaterName +'">' +item.theaterName +'</option>';
                locationString2 +='<option value="' +item.movieName +'">' +item.movieName +'</option>';
            });
            $('#secondselectbox').html(locationString);
            $('#thirdselectbox').html(locationString2);
            $('span#selectedMovie').text($('#thirdselectbox').val());
            $('span#selectedTheater').text($('#secondselectbox').val());
        }
    });

    $('#secondselectbox').on('change', function() {
        var theater = $(this).val();
        for(var i in locations){
            if(locations[i].theaterName===theater){
                $('span#selectedTheater').text(theater);
                $('span#selectedMovie').text(locations[i].movieName);
                $('#thirdselectbox').val(locations[i].movieName);
            }
        }
    });

    $('#thirdselectbox').on('change', function() {
        var movie = $(this).val();
        for(var i in locations){
            if(locations[i].movieName===movie){
                $('span#selectedMovie').text(movie);
                $('span#selectedTheater').text(locations[i].theaterName);
                $('#secondselectbox').val(locations[i].theaterName);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="UserData">
            <h1><a href="moviebooking.html">MyMovie-Ticket-Booking</a></h1>
            <select class="selectCity" id="selectCity">
                <option value="">Select City</option>
                <option value="Bengaluru">Bengaluru</option>
                <option value="Hyderabad">Hyderabad</option>
                <option value="Guntur">Guntur</option>
                <option value="Ongole">Ongole</option>
            </select>
            <span id="welcome"> </span>
            <p id="demo" class="cityName"></p>
        </div>
         <div class="MoviesList" id="List">
            <label class="TitleName">Movie Name:</label>
            <select id="thirdselectbox" class="TheaterList">
                <!--<option value="" selected disabled hidden>Select Movie</option>-->
                 <option selected="selected"> Select Movie </option>
            </select>
            <label class="TitleName">Theater Name:</label>
            <select id="secondselectbox" class="MovieList">
                 <option selected="selected"> Select Theater </option>
            </select>
          <fieldset class="Container">
            <legend class="selection">Your Selection</legend>
            <div class="TmName">
                Theater: <span id="selectedTheater"></span>
                <div style="width: 30%;margin: 0 auto;">
                    <button class="btn1" id="movieTimeings"></button><button class="btn1" id="movieTimeings"></button><button class="btn1" id="movieTimeings"></button><button class="btn1" id="movieTimeings"></button>
                </div>

                Movie: <span id="selectedMovie"></span>
            </div>
         </fieldset>
        </div>
```

I want to display the show timings along with selected movie or theater and display them in the buttons.

How do i do it? Pls help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

I've just edited your code snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var cityData = [
        {
            cityName: 'Bengaluru',
            value: 'Bengaluru',
            data: [
                {
                    movieName: 'ABC',
                    theaterName: 'Tulsi Theatre',
                    showTImings:['8:00AM','12:00PM','4:00PM','9:00PM']
                },
                {
                    movieName: 'DEF',
                    theaterName: 'PVR',
                    showTImings:['8:00AM','12:00PM','4:00PM','9:00PM']
                },
                {
                    movieName: 'GHI',
                    theaterName: 'Srinivasa Theatre',
                    showTImings:['8:00AM','12:00PM','4:00PM','9:00PM']
                },
            ],
        },
        {
            cityName: 'Hyderabad',
            value: 'Hyderabad',
            data: [
                {
                    movieName: '123',
                    theaterName: 'Theatre1',
                    showTImings:['8:00AM','12:00PM','4:00PM','9:00PM']
                },
                {
                    movieName: '456',
                    theaterName: 'PVR2',
                    showTImings:['8:00AM','12:00PM','4:00PM','9:00PM']
                },
                {
                    movieName: '789',
                    theaterName: 'Theatre3',
                    showTImings:['8:00AM','12:00PM','4:00PM','9:00PM']
                },
            ],
        },

        {
            cityName: 'Guntur',
            value: 'Guntur',
            data: [
                {
                    movieName: 'ABC1',
                    theaterName: 'Theatre4',
                    showTImings:['8:00AM','12:00PM','4:00PM','9:00PM']
                },
                {
                    movieName: 'DEF2',
                    theaterName: 'PVR3',
                    showTImings:['8:00AM','12:00PM','4:00PM','9:00PM']
                },
                {
                    movieName: 'GHI3',
                    theaterName: 'Theatre5',
                    showTImings:['8:00AM','12:00PM','4:00PM','9:00PM']
                },
            ],
        },

        {
            cityName: 'Ongole',
            value: 'Ongole',
            data: [],
        },
    ];
    
    var locations = [] ;
    $('#selectCity').on('change', function() {
        if ($(this).val().indexOf('City') === -1) {
        locations = cityData.filter( c => c.cityName === $(this).val(),)[0].data;
            var locationString = '';
            var locationString2 = '';
            
            if(locations.length == 0){
              $('#showTimings').html('No shows available');
            }
            
            $.each(locations, function(i, item) {
                locationString +='<option value="' +item.theaterName +'">' +item.theaterName +'</option>';
                locationString2 +='<option value="' +item.movieName +'">' +item.movieName +'</option>';
                
                $('#showTimings').html('');
                $.each(locations[i].showTImings,function(i,v){
                  var button = $('<button />').html(v);
                  $('#showTimings').append(button);
                });
            });
            $('#secondselectbox').html(locationString);
            $('#thirdselectbox').html(locationString2);
            $('span#selectedMovie').text($('#thirdselectbox').val());
            $('span#selectedTheater').text($('#secondselectbox').val());
            
            
        }
    });

    $('#secondselectbox').on('change', function() {
        var theater = $(this).val();
        for(var i in locations){
            if(locations[i].theaterName===theater){
                $('span#selectedTheater').text(theater);
                $('span#selectedMovie').text(locations[i].movieName);
                $('#thirdselectbox').val(locations[i].movieName);
                
                $('#showTimings').html('');
                $.each(locations[i].showTImings,function(i,v){
                  var button = $('<button />').html(v);
                  $('#showTimings').append(button);
                });
            }
        }
        
        
    });

    $('#thirdselectbox').on('change', function() {
        var movie = $(this).val();
        for(var i in locations){
            if(locations[i].movieName===movie){
                $('span#selectedMovie').text(movie);
                $('span#selectedTheater').text(locations[i].theaterName);
                $('#secondselectbox').val(locations[i].theaterName);
                
                $('#showTimings').html('');
                $.each(locations[i].showTImings,function(i,v){
                  var button = $('<button />').html(v);
                  $('#showTimings').append(button);
                });
                
                
                
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="UserData">
            <h1><a href="moviebooking.html">MyMovie-Ticket-Booking</a></h1>
            <select class="selectCity" id="selectCity">
                <option value="">Select City</option>
                <option value="Bengaluru">Bengaluru</option>
                <option value="Hyderabad">Hyderabad</option>
                <option value="Guntur">Guntur</option>
                <option value="Ongole">Ongole</option>
            </select>
            <span id="welcome"> </span>
            <p id="demo" class="cityName"></p>
        </div>
         <div class="MoviesList" id="List">
            <label class="TitleName">Movie Name:</label>
            <select id="thirdselectbox" class="TheaterList">
                <!--<option value="" selected disabled hidden>Select Movie</option>-->
                 <option selected="selected"> Select Movie </option>
            </select>
            <label class="TitleName">Theater Name:</label>
            <select id="secondselectbox" class="MovieList">
                 <option selected="selected"> Select Theater </option>
            </select>
          <fieldset class="Container">
            <legend class="selection">Your Selection</legend>
            <div class="TmName">
                Theater: <span id="selectedTheater"></span>
                <div id="showTimings" style="width: 30%;margin: 0 auto;">
                    <button class="btn1" id="movieTimeings"></button><button class="btn1" id="movieTimeings"></button><button class="btn1" id="movieTimeings"></button><button class="btn1" id="movieTimeings"></button>
                </div>

                Movie: <span id="selectedMovie"></span>
            </div>
         </fieldset>
        </div>
```

But can be made even simpler by not repeating the same code and moving it into functions and calling them.

Comment: i have one more doubt@sanatsathyan how to display the error message when selecting Ongole in select city option with out displaying any data?

Comment: i am trying that one but it shows data with error message but i want only error message

Comment: Is it possible to don't display movie name and theater name drop down and your selection session when selecting the Ongole in city delection@sanatsathyan

Comment: yes. just hide if there are no results, where i am showing that "no shows available" text and show when there are results.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the edited code

```
<div class="UserData">
    ...
  <fieldset class="Container">
    <legend class="selection">Your Selection</legend>
    <div class="TmName">
        Theater: <span id="selectedTheater"></span>
        <div style="width: 30%;margin: 0 auto;" class="movieTimings">
            <button class="btn1" id="movieTimeings"></button>
            <button class="btn1" id="movieTimeings"></button>
            <button class="btn1" id="movieTimeings"></button>
            <button class="btn1" id="movieTimeings"></button>
        </div>

        Movie: <span id="selectedMovie"></span>
    </div>
 </fieldset>
</div>
```

And the Edited script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var cityData = [
        {
            cityName: 'Bengaluru',
            value: 'Bengaluru',
            data: [
                {
                    movieName: 'ABC',
                    theaterName: 'Tulsi Theatre',
                    showTImings:['8:00AM','12:00PM','4:00PM','9:00PM']
                },
                {
                    movieName: 'DEF',
                    theaterName: 'PVR',
                    showTImings:['8:00AM','12:00PM','4:00PM','9:00PM']
                },
                {
                    movieName: 'GHI',
                    theaterName: 'Srinivasa Theatre',
                    showTImings:['8:00AM','12:00PM','5:00PM','9:00PM']
                },
            ],
        },

        {
            cityName: 'Hyderabad',
            value: 'Hyderabad',
            data: [
                {
                    movieName: '123',
                    theaterName: 'Theatre1',
                    showTImings:['8:00AM','12:00PM','4:00PM','9:00PM']
                },
                {
                    movieName: '456',
                    theaterName: 'PVR2',
                    showTImings:['8:00AM','12:00PM','4:00PM','9:00PM']
                },
                {
                    movieName: '789',
                    theaterName: 'Theatre3',
                    showTImings:['8:00AM','12:00PM','4:00PM','9:00PM']
                },
            ],
        },

        {
            cityName: 'Guntur',
            value: 'Guntur',
            data: [
                {
                    movieName: 'ABC1',
                    theaterName: 'Theatre4',
                    showTImings:['8:00AM','12:00PM','4:00PM','9:00PM']
                },
                {
                    movieName: 'DEF2',
                    theaterName: 'PVR3',
                    showTImings:['8:00AM','12:00PM','4:00PM','9:00PM']
                },
                {
                    movieName: 'GHI3',
                    theaterName: 'Theatre5',
                    showTImings:['8:00AM','12:00PM','4:00PM','9:00PM']
                },
            ],
        },

        {
            cityName: 'Ongole',
            value: 'Ongole',
            data: [],
        },
    ];

    // make locations global to track it
    var locations = [] ;
    $('#selectCity').on('change', function() {
        if ($(this).val().indexOf('City') === -1) {
            locations = cityData.filter( c => c.cityName === $(this).val(),)[0].data;
            var locationString = '';
            var locationString2 = '';
            $.each(locations, function(i, item) {
                locationString +='<option value="' +item.theaterName +'">' +item.theaterName +'</option>';
                locationString2 +='<option value="' +item.movieName +'">' +item.movieName +'</option>';
            });
            $('#secondselectbox').html(locationString);
            $('#thirdselectbox').html(locationString2);
            //    here we change the values of the current movie and theater
            $('span#selectedMovie').text($('#thirdselectbox').val());
            $('span#selectedTheater').text($('#secondselectbox').val());
        }
    });

    $('#secondselectbox').on('change', function() {
        // here the theater change
        // get the selected value
        var theater = $(this).val();
        // here we need to go through every element in locations
        for(var i in locations){
            // checks if the current element
            // check if its theater equal current theater
            // chenage the values
            if(locations[i].theaterName===theater){
                // here we change the data
                $('span#selectedTheater').text(theater);
                $('span#selectedMovie').text(locations[i].movieName);
                $('#thirdselectbox').val(locations[i].movieName);
            }
        }
    });

    $('#thirdselectbox').on('change', function() {
        // here the movie change
        // get the selected value
        var movie = $(this).val();
        // here we need to go through every element in locations
        for(var i in locations){
            // checks if the current element
            // check if its movie equal current movie
            // chenage the values
            if(locations[i].movieName===movie){
                    // here we change the data
                $('span#selectedMovie').text(movie);
                $('span#selectedTheater').text(locations[i].theaterName);
                // also we need the change the selection value
                $('#secondselectbox').val(locations[i].theaterName);


                var timingArray = locations[i].showTImings;
                var timingHtmlText = '';
                $.each( timingArray , function(k,v) {
                    timingHtmlText +='<button class="btn'+k+'" id="movieTimeings'+k+'">'+v+'</button>';
                });
                $('.movieTimings').html(timingHtmlText);
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```